# How to generate a 24bit Bitmap in android

Tags: java, android

I am working on android app that needs to generate a QRCode, and I successfully done with this.

My problem is on the printing side. I used a Mobiprint 3 device which has a built-in Thermal Printer. But my problem is the device printer only support a 24bit Bitmap.

My question is,  is there a way to create a 24bit Bitmap in android? since it only support a 32bit. I googled it in a week but no one solved my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The bitmap of android  does not work?

Comment: have you tried something? what type of error  you are getting?

Comment: @AkshayTilekar yes I tried something. I followed the tutorial in google zxing. It works fine in displaying. but when I call the bitmap for printing. It print a purely black square.

Comment: @josedlujan - Bitmap in android only works for display. but for printing it does'nt work :(

Answer (score 0):

BTW.

This is my code

//method for generating a QRCode Bitmap

```
    try {
        bitmap = qrGenerator.generateQRCode(duCode);
        int width, height;
        height = bitmap.getHeight();
        width = bitmap.getWidth();

        bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        cm.setSaturation(0);
        ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
        paint.setColorFilter(f);
        c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);

    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this is when calling the Bitmap for printing.

```
print.printBitmap(getBitmap());
```

this codes only prints a pure square black.

PS: print.printBitmap() is from the Mobiprint API.